# How to lay tile backer board on sandy cement floor

Tags: concrete, tiling

I've just removed some super old tiles from my bathroom floor.

Most of the now exposed concrete is in decent condition. However the cement is a little soft / sandy around the drain area (it's an old terraced house with extension over drain).

I'm laying tile backer boards over the floor before the tiles.

What should I do about this slight sandy area. Would it be ok to level with tile adhesive or should I try something else.

Pictures

[image]

[image]

Comment: By "the adhesive" do you mean thinset mortar? How deep is the decomposing concrete?

Comment: Added some images

Comment: And updated text - meant: tile adhesive

Answer (score 2):

You have to get rid of the sandy area/sand.   If there is just a thin layer and you have solid flooring under you can use a filler like a floor leveler - there are other options but I would need to see pictures.   If there is a thick layer or no solid flooring you are going to have to pour concrete or frame (which may be impossible).

There are solutions like floating a floor over the sand but these would break down over time - probably a lot faster than you think.   This is maybe an alternative in some climates and some situations.

Comment: Thanks for this! I'll get some pictures taken tomorrow.

Comment: Added a couple of images

Comment: Can you clean up the sand then take pictures?   It is hard to tell what is loose or solid in them.   From what I see it doesn't seem that bad but want to be sure.

Comment: That’s about it. The rest is ok. The depth of the recess is about 50mm max.

Answer (score 0):

I will clean and pour concrete if necessary I also will add fiber to concrete or solution to make it stronger.
You need a solid foundation to begin.